# why does my app crashes when I try to find a view that is in different xml files

Tags: android

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("hello world");

}
```

here the textview is present in a different xml file other than activity.main xml file.

Comment: Let us see your `activity_main.xml`...

Answer (score 0):

To use views from XML you have to inflate them.  setContentView(int id) is doing some background inflating for you on R.layout.activity_main but you can't get a handle to the TextView because it is not inflated.  I can't imagine why you would want to do something with a view from a hierarchy that you are not displaying;  in any case I doubt this is the way you want to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

This simply won't work, as the current inflated view points to `activity_main` and the so the `findViewById()` method looks for `TextView` in the `activity_main` file.

For finding the `TextView` in other file, you will first have to inflate that view (in you case the another xml file).